# getting user input without using input element

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to get the user text input without having him type in a text box, or somehow concealing the text box.
i would want to build something like a table cell with text in it and when the user clicks on the cell he can edit the text there.

Comment: Like this? https://codepen.io/ashblue/pen/mCtuA

Comment: There are several ways: for instance with a `contenteditable` HTML property, or with an input that only appears after the click and takes the corresponding value into it, ...etc. Search a bit about those possibilities and try one.

Comment: You could get real creative with Javascript and log their key strokes and update some div on the page to show which keys have been pressed so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contenteditable`:

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
 console.log(e.target.innerText)
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="foo" contenteditable="true">Foo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use editable tables like html5 editable table, click 
   (https://codepen.io/ashblue/pen/mCtuA) for example!

```
enter code here
```